# Assign variables from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I created a settings table in my database and I would like to assign value to a variable based on the setting and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

table: settings

```
id | setting       | value
1  | setting_one   | value_one
2  | setting_two   | value_two
3  | setting_three | value_three
```

Query

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings")) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $SettingOne   = $row['setting_one'];
        $SettingTwo   = $row['setting_two'];
        $SettingThree = $row['setting_three'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to set them to individual variables? You can just carry around the array and access them in that by the key.

Comment: Do `${$row['setting']} = $row['value'];` to get something set like `$setting_one='value_one';`

Comment: But you should work with the array directly, instead of creating new variables

Answer (score 0):

The select will return you 3 rows, assuming your table has only 3 rows in it
 that is why you process the result in a while lop.

Each `$row` will contain an Assoc array in the form of the columns that you selected in your query.

In this case as you use `SELECT *` the `$row` array will contain 3 occurances

```
id, setting, value
```

So your loop should look like

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings")) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id       = $row['id'];
        $setting  = $row['setting'];
        $value    = $row['value'];

        echo "The id = $id, the setting = $setting, the value is $value <br>";
    }
}
```

This will produce you 3 lines of output, assuming you only have 3 rows in your table

Comment: Ok, now let's say I have two settings in there now.
id=1, setting=setting_timezone, value=America/New_York
id=2, setting=setting_static_ip, value=false

How do I assign the values of the settings to variables?

$SettingTimezone = setting_timezone
$SettingStaticIP    = setting_static_ip

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out and just echo the row['setting'] as $setting for each :)

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings")) {   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $key = $row['setting'];
        $$key = $row['value'];
    }
$result->free();
$result->close();
}
```